# Validation using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

1)I have a field with the value as 11/06-13 (YY/DD-MM) how can i validate this value using regex.

2)I have a field with value 08:00 how can i validate this value using regex.

3)I have a field with value 2015-12-02+03:00 (YYYY-MM-DD+hh:mm) how can i validate this value using regex.

Please help i am new to regex.

Comment: Use a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us where your issue is?

This question as it stands now is considered off-topic. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Just read the Javadoc about Regular Expressions.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

You can use

```
Pattern.matches(regex, Input);
```

to validate your Strings.

For your first Point it would be:

```
Pattern.matches("[0-9]{2}/[0-3][0-9]-(0|1)[0-9]", date);
```

The year can range from 00 to 99 followed by a "/". The day can range from 00 to 39. If you want to check for a valid day you can use:

```
(0[1-9])|((1|2)[0-9])|(30|1)
```

Now the day must be between 01 and 31.

The month can range from 00 to 19 in my first example. To avoid that you can use:

```
(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])
```

Complete Regex:

```
[0-9]{2}/((0[1-9])|((1|2)[0-9])|(30|1))-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolay.. I tried below logic & it worked
1. (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(1[3-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9])
2.(0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-4]):(0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0])
3.(19|20)\\d\\d-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\+\\d\\d:\\d\\d